# Unable to connect adb in wsl2 to windows adb server

Tags: android, automation, adb, wsl-2

My requirement is simple - I wanted to use ADB in wsl2. But there is no USB support in wsl2, so I took help from github issue [#4619](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4619#issuecomment-596990676) and enable access to wsl2 section in [Building a react native app in WSL2](https://gist.github.com/bergmannjg/461958db03c6ae41a66d264ae6504ade#enable-access-to-adb-server-from-wsl2). Yet nothing works. Following are the steps I took:

1. Downloaded sdk platform tools from [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools) for windows. Ran `adb --version` which is `Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41`
2. Downloaded the same for linux for wsl and unzipped and checked the version to be the same. (Also made changes to .bashrc to have it point to adb where I unzipped)
3. Connected mobile with usb which had the USB and wireless debugging option on.
4. Ran `adb devices` in windows to check if I could see my mobile being listed and it was. Then ran `adb kill-server` to proceed with the next steps.
5. Did the same in wsl2 to see if the device is listed or not , but it wasn't. So I ran `adb kill-server` to proceed with the next steps.
6. Tried [#4619](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4619#issuecomment-596990676) and [Building a react native app in WSL2](https://gist.github.com/bergmannjg/461958db03c6ae41a66d264ae6504ade#enable-access-to-adb-server-from-wsl2) but to no avail.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

To access device from WSL, you need to run `adb` on Windows and then redirect the `adb` commands from WSL to the windows `adb` server.

From the guide that you linked:

- https://gist.github.com/bergmannjg/461958db03c6ae41a66d264ae6504ade#start-adb-server-in-windows - this starts a server in Windows
- https://gist.github.com/bergmannjg/461958db03c6ae41a66d264ae6504ade#enable-access-to-adb-server-from-wsl2 - this prepares WSL to connect to Windows

**Attention**: do not stop the windows `adb` server!! You need it!!